# PHP, MYSQL send email with pdf attachement from database

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have a table like this:

```
file_id : INT
file_name : VARCHAR[20]
file_data : BLOB
```

I store PDF files inside and I want to send an email(using PHP) with an attachment from the database.Any ideeas or guidelines?

Edit: I don't want to download it and then attach it and after that delete the temp file.

Comment: Google is always good. lmgt fy.com/?q=send+attachment+php (remove the space)

Comment: I have googled it but I need to attach it directly from the database. Is not quite the same beacuse i don't want to download it and then attach it and after that delete the temp file.

Comment: Get the document from the database, and attach it? Store the document as a blob?

Comment: Storing files as a blob in DB will dramatically increase its size (DB), depending on how many files you have and the documents' size also. It's best to hold the files in a secure area, and link to the document in a column. @meska

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$path = "temp/";
$my_file="file.pdf";

$from_name = "hhhhh";

$from_mail = "abc@gmail.com";

$mailto = "abc@gmail.com";

$subject = "This is a mail with attachment.";

$message = "Hi,\r\n do you got attachment?\r\n\r\Hara";

$replyto="haraprasad@lemonpeak.com";
$file = $path.$my_file;
    $file_size = filesize($file);


$handle = fopen($file, "r");

$content = fread($handle, $file_size);

fclose($handle);

$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

$name = basename($file);

 $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";

$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

 $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";

$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";

$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";

$header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";

$header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$name."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here

$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$name."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";

$header .= "--".$uid."--";

mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header) 

?>
```